# How to find how many numbers present in a given number?

Tags: python

I'm using the following approach to find how many `m = 2` present in `c = 5`:

```py
number_of_two = 0
while c > 1:
    c -= m
    number_of_two += 1
```

I want to use some libraries like itertools or something to find how many `m` is present in a given `c`.

Comment: are you trying to find the quotient? that would be  `c // m`

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer, as [@njzk2](https://stackoverflow.com/users/671543/njzk2) [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62178910/how-to-find-how-many-numbers-present-in-a-given-number#comment109970032_62178910), is the quotient which is calculated like this:

```py
number_of_m = c // m
```

or by using the [`divmod` built-in function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#divmod):

```py
number_of_m = divmod(c, m)[0]
```

But if you want to use a library like [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html), I suggest this code:

```py
from itertools import accumulate, takewhile, repeat
import operator
import math

c = int(input())  # or 5 in your example
m = int(input())  # or 2 in your example

# Don't forget to check for exceptions first
if m == 0:
    number_of_m = math.inf
elif m < 0:
    raise ValueError("m must be a non-negative number.")  # IMO, there are no negative numbers in a positive number
else:
    number_of_m = len(list(takewhile(lambda x: x >= 0, accumulate(repeat(m), operator.sub, initial=c)))) - 1
```

All the work is done in the last line, which calculates the answer in a way similar to your example code, but in one line.

Also if you are interested in [python's built-in functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html), I suggest this code:

```py
import math

c = int(input())
m = int(input())

if m == 0:
    number_of_m = math.inf
elif m < 0:
    raise ValueError("m must be a non-negative number.")
else:
    number_of_m = len(list(filter(lambda x: x % m == 0, range(1, c + 1))))
```